# White spaces when updating varchar field using iif in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I see strange result when executing this query

```
update sd_invodt set line_type=iif(is_promo=1, 'campaign', 'item')
```

The value in line_type field will be `"item   "`. There are whitespaces in value.
But when I execute this query

```
update sd_invodt set line_type='item'
```

I don't get white spaces.

Now I have to use trim as workaround

```
update sd_invodt set line_type=trim(iif(is_promo=1, 'campaign', 'item'))
```

I use latest firebird 2.5. Line_type is a varchar(15).

Is this bug in Firebird?

**EDIT**

I have tested using new database, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result type of the `iif()` depends on input and in case of string the result type seems to be `char(x)` where `x` is the length of the longest input string. Thus the `"item"` will be padded with 4 spaces to make it as long as the "campaign" is. I think this is by design but you may want to enter an ticket to the [FB issuetracker](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org).

So the `iif()` return `"item    "` in case of first parameter being false and when you store spaces onto `varchar` field they are preserved.

Comment: It is not considered a bug, see [CORE-4147](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4147)